# Angular / Karma / Jasmine test run succeed although one test fails

Tags: angular, testing, karma-jasmine

I'm using Angular 16.2 and karma / jasmine for unit tests

```
"jasmine-core": "~4.6.0",
"karma": "~6.4.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
"karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
"karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
```

I found out that when a test fails with the well known error

```
Error: NG0304: 'app-sub-component' is not a known element
```

due to a missing declaration in the TestBed.configureTestingModule, running all test suites succeed although one of them fails.

I want the whole test run to fail when one of them fails.

I got it by adding

```
errorOnUnknownElements: true,
```

in the TestBed.configureTestingModule. As I have many tests I'd like to set it up globally for all test suites.

Another track was to add stopOnSpecFailure in karma.conf file

```
client: {
  jasmine: {
    random: false,
    stopOnSpecFailure:true,
    failFast: true
```

unfortunately with no success.
Any idea ?